# Table valued function (TVF) on a comma-separated field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have this table:

```
create table Test (Value varchar(111))
insert Test select 'a,b,c'
```

I want to create a table valued function where I pass `Test.Value` and it returns the below table:

[image]

Where `Value` comes from `Test` table, and `Item` values are generated in this way: first item is whole value by itself (in example it consists of  three comma-separated values), once there aren't any three comma-separated values, we go from left to right for two comma-separated values.

We go strictly from left to right, so there isn't any need for items like `a,c` or `b,a`. And then we go finally to one comma-separated value, which is `a`, `b` and `c`.

`ItemLayer` is just a layer which is being processed. Obviously, the separator should be a comma, and `tvf` should return `Item` and `ItemLayer`. I think the query should look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test t
CROSS JOIN fn_getItemsFromValues(t.Value) f
```

I think there should be some sort of a recursive CTE, but I can't figure it out how.

Here is an output if `Value` was `'a,b,c,d'`:

[image]

I'm using SQL Server 2017. I've tried this, but I'm stuck. Something is very off here.

```
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(100) = 'a,b,c'
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @data TXT, LEFT(@data,1) Col1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT STUFF(TXT,1,1,'') TXT, LEFT(TXT,1) Col1 FROM CTE
    WHERE LEN(TXT) > 0
)
select Col1,txt from CTE
```

Comment: Please edit your question to: 1) specify the version of SQL Server you are using (that matters in this case) and 2) show the UDF code you have written so far and explain why it's not working for you.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning , done

Comment: @EricKlaus . . . Why don't you have `'a,c'` as a combination?

Comment: @GordonLinoff , I don't need to. I need to go strictly from left to right without any skips. in a,c we skip b, that's why we son't have it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why `a,c` is not in the list.  But you can generate all combinations by splitting the string and then using a recursive CTE:

```
with t as (
      select t.value, convert(varchar(max), s.value) as val
      from test t cross apply
           string_split(t.value, ',') s
     ),
     cte as (
      select t.value, t.val as str, t.val as lastval, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select cte.value, concat(cte.str, ',', t.val), t.val, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.value = t.value and cte.lastval < t.val
     )
select cte.*, dense_rank() over (order by lev desc) as itemlayer
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ef596ea578cf5c436c8f63352d823c1) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

I think the best approach to the "adjacent" limitation is really a tweak on the previous solution.  This adds a locator for the element and just allows the next element to be brought in on the recursive step:

```
with t as (
      select t.value, convert(varchar(max), s.value) as val,
             row_number() over (order by charindex(',' + s.value + ',', ',' + t.value + ',')) as ind
      from test t cross apply
           string_split(t.value, ',') s
     ),
     cte as (
      select t.value, t.val as str, t.ind, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select cte.value, concat(cte.str, ',', t.val), t.ind, lev + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.value = t.value and t.ind = cte.ind + 1
     )
 select cte.*, dense_rank() over (order by lev desc) as itemlayer
from cte;
```

This doesn't work if you have duplicate elements.  If that is the case, ask a new question.

Comment: something very close.I don't need to have a,c because both items in it are not next to each other (it skips b).

Comment: ok, this works only if Value strings  are 1 character, but if it has 'a,bz,c' it fails. I have another thing that might help. instead of using string_split, i have another similar tvf (`fn_splitwithorder(t.Value,',')`) which returns 2 fields: `Value,ValueOrder`, where `ValueOrder` is the order in which is appears, aka a has ValueOrder 1, b-2, c-3. i'm not sure how to incorporate that into above script, but i think it  might help

Comment: @EricKlaus . . . I edited the question with a better approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll probably spend a day to fully understand how that works. I knew that I should have used recursive CTE, but my brain couldn't go any further than simple things

Comment: What is "a/c"? Do you mean "a,c" (not a rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got:

```
drop function if exists fn_getItemsFromValues 
go
create function fn_getItemsFromValues (@val varchar(100))
returns @ret table
(
[value] varchar (100)
,item varchar (100)
,ItemLayer int
) 
as
begin
    declare
        @v varchar (1000)=@val
        ,@i int=1
        ,@J int=1
        ,@v_n varchar (1000)=''

    set @v=@val
    declare
        @t table (val varchar (1000))


    while @i<=len(@v)
    begin
        set @j=1
        while @i+@J-1<=len(@v)
        begin
            set @v_n=substring (@v, @i, @j)
            if len(@v_n)>1
                set @v_n=isnull(nullif(LEFT(@v_n,1),',') ,'') +substring (@v_n,2, len(@v_n)-2)+isnull(nullif(right(@v_n,1),',') ,'')

            insert into @t
            select @v_n where @v_n!=','
            set @j=@j+1
        end
    set @i=@i+1
    end

    insert into @ret
    select @v, val, count(ln) over (partition by ln) 
    from (
        select distinct val, len(val) ln from @t
        )t
    return
end

--select * from  dbo.fn_getItemsFromValues ('a,b,c,d') order by 3
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.